# copy.deepcopy raises TypeError on objects with self-defined __new__() method

Tags: python, deep-copy

I want to implement a symbol type, which keeps track of the symbols we already have(saved in `_sym_table`), and return them if they exist, or create new ones otherwise. The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

_sym_table = {}

class Symbol(object):
    def __new__(cls, sym):
        if sym not in _sym_table:
            return super().__new__(cls)
        else:
            return _sym_table[sym]

    def __init__(self, sym):
        self.sym = sym
        _sym_table[sym] = self

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sym

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return self is other

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.sym.__hash__()
```

But when I call `copy.deepcopy` on a list of such `Symbol` instances, exception is raised:

```
a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
s = [a, b]
t = copy.deepcopy(s)
```

Error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 7, in <module>
    t = copy.deepcopy(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/copy.py", line 147, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/copy.py", line 209, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/copy.py", line 285, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/copyreg.py", line 88, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So my questions are:

- How can I make a deep copy on these objects with self-defined `__new__` methods?
- And any suggestions about when and how to use `copy.deepcopy`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

one problem is that `deepcopy` and `copy` have no way of knowing which arguments to pass to `__new__`, therefore they only work with classes that don't require constructor arguments.

the reason why you can have `__init__` arguments is that `__init__` isn't called when copying an object, but `__new__` must be called to create the new object.

so if you want to control copying, you'll have to define the special `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` methods:

```
def __copy__(self):
    return self

def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    return self
```

by the way, [singletons](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/) are [evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx) and not really needed in python.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you want the Symbol instances to be singletons. Deepcopy, however is supposed to be used when you want an exact copy of an instance, i.e. a different instance that is equal to the original.

So the usage here kinda contradicts the purpose of deepcopy. If you want to make it work anyhow, you can define the [__deepcopy__](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) method on *Symbol*.

Answer (score 0):

Define `__getnewargs__` — that way you will not only be able to `copy` and `deepcopy`, but you'll also be able to `pickle`.